# redrection the view after 3 seconds to anther view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

i create application for iphone with xcode 5,1 and ios 6,0

I want to create a view that contains the name of my application after 3 seconds this view will be redirect to another view that contains processing my application

My Main.storyboard like this 
[image]

In My Class Icoz i have

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"yesss");
    Demmarage *d = [[Demmarage alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:d animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"merdeee");
}
```

but nothing happend when i build my application

How I can execute my application i want have the view "icoz" for 3 sec & after i want show the view "myblan"

Comment: What you mean by "nothing happens"? Have you even gotten your initial view to display?

Comment: yes i have just the view icoz and nothing happens after :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I can not see if your initialViewController is a `UINavigationViewController`. If not, your statemant `self.navigationController` is nil which might be the reason why nothing happens"

In your storyboard a segue is visible, you can perform this segue delayed within your `viewDidAppear`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    double delayInSeconds = 3.0; //seconds to wait
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TheNameOfTheSegue" sender:self];
    });
}
```

Another option, without the GCD and without a segue would be the following – simply pushing by using a navigation controller:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(pushDemmarage:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    //or use the following line instead of NSTimer
    //[self performSelector:@selector(pushDemmarage:) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
}

-(void)pushDemmarage:(id)sender
{
    Demmarage *d = [[Demmarage alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:d animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `FirstViewController`

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 //push you secondview controller on GCD with delay
 dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3*NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
  Demmarage *d = [[Demmarage alloc] init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:d animated:YES];

 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  a `NSTimer` to stay in the first controller for 3seconds. Do this in your first controller

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(loadSecondViewController:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

-(void)loadSecondViewController:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SecondViewSegueIdentifier sender:self];

}
```

Here `MPSecondViewSegueIdentifier` is the segue between first and second view controllers

Answer (score 0):

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(callMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void)callMethod
{

    // Do what u want here.
    Demmarage *d = [[Demmarage alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:d animated:YES];

}
```

Try this code..

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
(void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;
```